# Website Very Slow

Tags: performance, yslow, mod-pagespeed

Why does my website takes so long to load despite Good Yslow score. I am using YSlow and gtmetrix to test the speed of my website. I have scored 91% in Page Speed Grade and 89% in YSlow. But the Page load time: 4.67s which is relatively very slow. I have searched everywhere else with similar issue as mine, and it seems no one has found the solution to this yet.

Comment: Impossible to help you without a link to your website.

Comment: The first request to retrieve your HTML to my machine took 4.3 seconds.  Your performance bottleneck isn't on the front-end, it's in the PHP.  Troubleshoot that first.

Comment: Well I do I find the specif part of my code that is causing this?

Comment: @user3740975 Very often when the web response time is multiple seconds, bad database queries are a big reason. I'd run your database queries manually and see what turns up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 19 requests, totaling 5.3 seconds.  The first one took 4.3 seconds (the HTML) with the remainder being the remaining assets including your JS, CSS and images.

Your performance bottleneck isn't on the front-end, it's in the PHP.  You need to investigate that side of things a little further.  You need to narrow it down to which piece of code is causing the issue.  Perhaps you have some SQL which is taking a long time to load, in which case, try turning them off to confirm this is where your problem lies.

Comment: How to I investigate it? Is there any other software that I can use to find what is causing this?

Comment: Break it down and analyse each part of your code. You could start by commenting our everything, then progressively adding in functionality one piece at a time.  This will tell you where the problem is.  You probably don't need extra software to help with the analysis at this stage.

Comment: Okay thanks for the tips! I'll accept your answer in 3 min

Comment: By all means post a new question if you find another area of your program which is causing problems.  However my money is on an unoptimised SQL query. ;)